# How to unwrap optional value in swift?

Tags: swift

code correct

```
              print(error!.localizedDescription)
             }else{
            return
```

Comment: You should first figure out _what_ is nil, then think about how to deal with it. Replacing it with another value is not always the solution. So what is nil?

Comment: Yes... I can see that you have passed `nil` to the `metadata` parameter in your code, so that's obviously not what I am asking. Which value that you are force unwrapping is nil?

Answer (score 0):

To replace a nil value we need to unwrap optional value this done according to type of value.

i.e. if value is string then we need to add ?? "" or if value is double we need to add ?? 0.0

As in case of the above scenario  (EmailTextField.text ?? "") this is the format to replace unwrap optional value .

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: (txtEmail.text ?? ""), password: (txtPass.text ?? "")) { (result, error) in
        if let _eror = error {
            //something bad happning
            print(_eror.localizedDescription )
        }else{
            //user registered successfully
            print(result)
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

This error clearly indicates that you have forced unwrap the optional somewhere in your code.

Remove force unwrapping (!) by optional binding in your code.

Ways to optional binding...

1. if let
2. guard let
3. nil coalescing i.e ??

> Look for exclaimation mark in your code, where you have force
>   unwrapped and replace it with one of the above way.